# jQuery Tooltip Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I am looking for a straightforward jQuery tooltip script. I have been having troubles finding one that has a fixed position and doesn't move with the user's cursor. If anyone knows of one let me know :) Thanks!

Comment: Didn't you find **any** of the answers helpful?

Comment: jQuery tooltip lists http://www.designerslib.com/tag/jquery-tooltip/

Answer (score 1):

See there's this thing here called a [search engine](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=jquery+tooltip&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7943f865cd6ba416&biw=1067&bih=696)...

*Okay, okay... I'll be more constructive...*

My favorite is [qTip 2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download).  It does everything you want it to do.  *and you don't have to leave money on the table...*

Comment: Nice try. You got +2 for linking to Google and then edited your question with qTip2 an hour after my answer.

Comment: FYI I didn't even see your post nor care.  qTip and the one from bassistance.de are very well known plug-ins, obviously.  I got +2?  What did you dvote me?

Answer (score 1):

I always use this one here:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

It has the option to both follow the cursor AND keep it's position, along with a few other helpful options. The css is also very minimal and therfore easy to change.

Answer (score 1):

**I use [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) from [http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/).**

By default, it does **not** move with the cursor.  There are a bunch of options and some themes.  The best part is that the developer answers all questions in his forum within a day or less.

**Also here are some good ones meeting your requirement that it not follow the mouse cursor:**

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/

http://edgarverle.com/BetterTip/default.cfm

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

http://labs.dmlogica.com/dmltip/#more-53

http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/javascript-tooltip-jtip.html

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bt

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-better-tooltip-with-jquery-awesomeness/

http://www.dvq.co.nz/jquery/create-a-jquery-popup-bubble-effect/

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

http://css-plus.com/2010/04/create-a-speech-bubble-tooltip-using-css3-and-jquery/

http://gdakram.github.com/JQuery-Tooltip-Plugin/

As a side note, I'd stay away from the tool tip plugin that's part of **jQuery Tools by Flowplayer**.  IMHO, jQ Tools is poorly implemented, out of date and not supported very well by the developer or his community.

**100 various solutions on this page (however, some are not jQuery):**

http://www.webdesignshock.com/showcase/best-tooltip-scripts-plugins/

Comment: Quite a list!  The Web Design Shock page in particular is very extensive!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The one I always use is: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/colortips-jquery-tooltip-plugin/

It's three short CSS lines to customize colors and easy to work with!

Comment: If it's three short CSS lines, it would be better to include them in the answer rather than forcing readers to visit a link.