# Facebook-like JavaScript popup help

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you look at the following screenshot:

[image]
You will see a popup box **(NOT THE MODAL)** with some content that says 'Security Check' which is basically some helpful information that the user can invoke by clicking a link. I know how to create similar things using jQuery and simple HTML/CSS but looking at the Facebook example I have noticed that the help box **IS NOT** in the source...

Therefore it is being loaded in from somewhere else and then displayed to the user in the DOM... how would I create something similar?

Thanks

Comment: You can create it from scratch as described in answers below or you could use a jQuery **Tooltip** plugin.  There are dozens... qTip2 is one example.  [see my answer in this thread.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061541/jquery-tooltip-script)

Answer (score 4):

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EYghv/

**html:**

```
<a href="#">What's this?</a>

<div class="tooltip">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="content">
        Security Check:<br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - 20;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop + 22;
    $(".tooltip").show().css({
        left: x,
        top: y
    }).delay(3000).fadeOut();
    return false;
});

$(".tooltip").click(function() {
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

**css:**

```
.tooltip {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;  
}
.triangle {
    font-size:0px;
    line-height:0px;
    width:0px;
    border-bottom:20px solid #fec;
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
}
.content {
    background-color:#fec;
    width:300px;
    padding:5px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.load()` to load it into the popup div.

```
$('#popupDiv').load('popurl.html');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/RjxbQ/show/

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/RjxbQ/

Popup: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/83L52/

Comment: What if I didn't want to use fake pages?

Comment: @Cameron, i added a fiddle demo

Comment: @cameron, now the popup loads where the mouse is

Answer (score 0):

You can store the element in a variable and insert it as desired. This method lends itself well to templating (making a template popup that you can insert a string or whatever into):

```
var myPopup = "<div class='my_popup'>Some Helpful Whatnot</div>";
$('#some_link_id').live('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#some_link_id').append(myPopup);
});
```